# same server listening on different sockets

Tags: java, sockets, udp, multicast, multicastsocket

I have a UDP multicast server listening on 2 sockets on 2 different ports. I achieved listening on these 2 sockets from clients. But i want to identify on which socket a client is sending a packet. Since my problem is that ; on the server if I listen on socket(9999) and if the client is sending on socket(8888) then at the server side I want it to identify the incoming packet is from which port.

```
public class MulticastReceiver 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      MulticastSocket socket = null;
      DatagramPacket packet  = null;

      MulticastSocket soc = null;
      byte[] inBuf = null;
      try
      {
          socket = new MulticastSocket(8888);
          soc = new MulticastSocket(9999);

          InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("224.2.2.3");
          socket.joinGroup(address);
          soc.joinGroup(address);

          System.out.println("224.2.2.3 ready to receive packets");
          while(true)
          {
              inBuf=new byte[256];

              packet = new DatagramPacket(inBuf,inBuf.length);
              System.out.println("port is: "+ packet.getAddress() + packet.getPort());
              if(packet.getPort() == 9999) 
              {
                  soc.receive(packet);
              //System.out.println("Data at 224.2.2.3:: " + new String(packet.getData()));
              }
              else
                  socket.receive(packet);

              System.out.println("Data at 224.2.2.3:: " + new String(packet.getData()));
          }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {

      }


  }
}





public class MulticastSender {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    DatagramPacket outPacket = null;
    byte[] outBuf;
    final int PORT = 8888;

    try {
      socket = new DatagramSocket();
      long counter = 0;
      String msg;

        msg = "This is multicast! ";

        outBuf = msg.getBytes();

        //Send to multicast IP address and port
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("224.2.2.3");
        outPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuf, outBuf.length, address, PORT);

        socket.send(outPacket);

        System.out.println("Server sends : " + msg);
        try {
          Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println(ioe);
    }
  }
}




public class AnotherSender {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    DatagramPacket outPacket = null;
    byte[] outBuf;
    final int PORT = 9999;

    try {
      socket = new DatagramSocket();
      long counter = 0;
      String msg;

        msg = "This is another multicast! " + counter;
        counter++;
        outBuf = msg.getBytes();

        //Send to multicast IP address and port
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("224.2.2.3");
        outPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuf, outBuf.length, address, PORT);

        socket.send(outPacket);

        System.out.println("Server sends : " + msg);
        try {
          Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println(ioe);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make sense. The packet won't have a port number at all until you put one into it or `receive()` does, and at best this will just read alternately between the two sockets, blocking each time, possibly forever, receiving from one socket, and thus starving the other one.

You need a receiving thread for each non-blocking socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not even slightly impressed with your pointless edit.

Comment: I wasn't trying to impress you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Let's put it this way. My original statement was too loose in that it didn't specify 'non-blocking'. Your edit made it worse, by implying that it applied not just to all sockets but to all ports.